# Trying to get Excel to create a new list with multiple criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

I may be asking too much of Excel, or maybe I just can't figure it out. I want to create a list that is a subset of another list based on two criteria that are unique.

The input list is in one sheet in the range Sheet1!B9:B20. The list elements are text, and are in the form of: NNNN - Text description (E.g. 1320 - Owner Expense). It's those first four characters that are important. It is a GL code.

The output list is a subset of the input one. I need to exclude elements where a) the GL code begins with '4', and b) the GL code is on a list of excluded 4-digit codes (E.g. 1320), listed as text in Sheet3!A2:A20. So, for example:

```
Input list:                     Output list
1000 - Description 1    --->    1000 - Description 1  
1320 - Description 2            5110 - Description 4  
4000 - Description 3  
5110 - Description 4
```

...where 4000 begins with a '4' and 1320 is on the excluded list.

Here's the code that successfully excludes the items beginning with '4':

```
Note the {} brackets; it's an array formula.

{=IFERROR(
INDEX(Sheet1!B$9:B$20,
SMALL(
IF(
LEFT(Sheet1!$B$9:$B$20,1)<>"4",    // I can enter only a single condition here
ROW(Sheet1!B$9:B$20)-ROW(Sheet1!B$9)+1
),
ROWS(Sheet1!B$9:'SS Version'!B9)
)
),"")}
```

I tried the following conditions with no luck:

```
AND(LEFT(Sheet1!$B$9:$B$20,1)<>"4", LEFT(Sheet1!$B$9:$B$20,4)<>Sheet3!$A$2:$A$20),

AND(LEFT(Sheet1!$B$9:$B$20,1)<>"4", LEFT(Sheet1!$B$9:$B$20,4)<>{"1320","1330", excluded code list},
```

I'm not adverse to have all the 4XXX codes added to my excluded list and use only that list, but that didn't work either when I tried it. The condition I tried was:

```
LEFT(Sheet1!$B$9:$B$20,4)<>Sheet3!$A$2:$A$20),
```

Have a suggestion?

Comment: You could create the second list by using a filter

Answer (score 0):

You may use an **Advanced Filter** to create a new list in another location.

See the screenshot for the setup.
`Excluded` is the range of cells on `Sheet 2` that includes your excluded list.

### Formulas

```
A2:   =LEFT(A7)<>"4"
B2:   =ISERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/ISNUMBER(FIND(Excluded,A7))))
```

*The formula in B2 is a bit convoluted as array formulas are not permitted as criterion in the Advanced Filter.*

[image]

Comment: Hmm, this is new to me. Thanks Ron, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I have not arrived at the complete solution but this is very close to what I think you are looking for:

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(INDEX(Sheet1!$B$9:$B$20,SMALL(
IF(
LEFT(Sheet1!$B$9:$B$20,1)<>"4",
ROW(Sheet1!B$9:B$20)-ROW(Sheet1!B$9)+1
),
ROW()-8
)),4)),Sheet3!A:A,0)),INDEX(Sheet1!$B$9:$B$20,SMALL(
IF(
LEFT(Sheet1!$B$9:$B$20,1)<>"4",
ROW(Sheet1!B$9:B$20)-ROW(Sheet1!B$9)+1
),
ROW()-8
)))
```

This is returning the result but there are the FALSE rows in between which I haven't been able to get rid off.

**My input list in Sheet1 was as below in A9:B20:**

```
1   1000 - Description 1    
2   1320 - Description 2 on exlusion list   
3   4000 - Description 3    
4   5110 - Description 4    
5   4100 - Description 5    
6   2230 - Description 6 on exclusion list  
7   3330 - Description 7 on exclusion list  
8   6000 - Description 8    
9   7000 - Description 9    
10  5330 - Description 10 on exclusion list 
11  blank
12  blank
```

**Exclusions on Sheet3 is as below (column A):**

```
1320
2230
3330
5330
```

**Output looks like this:**

```
1000 - Description 1
FALSE
5110 - Description 4
FALSE
FALSE
6000 - Description 8
7000 - Description 9
FALSE
0
0
FALSE
FALSE
```

I know that this is not a complete answer but putting it over here to that someone can build up on top of my work while I am still trying to crack this. I do not have enough credentials to add comments.